# Trying to monitor the internals of a rails application with nagios and nrpe but only getting "NRPE: Unable to read output"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monitoring, nagios, nrpe

I'm trying to monitor the internals of a rails application with `nagios` and `nrpe` plugin but only getting `NRPE: Unable to read output`

**Here is my Monitoring Machine Code "check_test.rb" script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# load rails

RAILS_ENV = 'production'
require '/var/www/production/current/config/environment'

error = 0

print "OK"

exit error # exit with the error code that is then interpreted by nagios
```

Here is my Monitoring Host call:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H remote.machine.com -c check_test -t 240
```

**If I remove the lines below, it works fine:**

```
# load rails

RAILS_ENV = 'production'
require '/var/www/production/current/config/environment'
```

Any help will be very much appretiated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I created a wrapper bash script as follows:

---

#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/production/current/

RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_test.rb --silent

exit $?

---

And removed the RAILS_ENV statement from check_test.rb since It was already declared into the wrapper script.

It is now working fine :-DD

Thanks!

Comment: Another option would be: `cd /var/www/production/current/ && script/rails runner -e [ENVIRONMENT] 'YOUR_CLASS.YOUR_METHOD'`